# Reliable (cryptographic) way to verify a devices public IP address behind a NAT

Tags: linux, bash, security, cryptography, dyndns

I am writing a relatively small bash script that is supposed to update DNS records for a server behind a NAT which might change its external IP address. Essentially a free DynDNS using my DNS provider's API.

I am retrieving the server's IP address using a simple query to an external service. But for the sake of security, before pointing my DNS `A` record to a new arbitrary IP address given to my by an external service I first need to verify that this indeed is the server's IP address. And this check would need to involve a cryptography step since an active MITM attack could be taking place and just forwarding traffic to the server's real IP address.

So what would be the simplest way (if possible through bash) to verify that this is indeed the server's IP address?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Cryptography Stack Exchange](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/) or [Information Security Stack Exchange](http://security.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: The immediate answer is probably along the lines of, sign the request to update DNS information. However a lot of context is missing so it would not be wise to speculate further. You should discuss your protocol on another site, like [Cryptography Stack Exchange](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/) or [Information Security Stack Exchange](http://security.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: For the part about *"I am retrieving the server's IP address using a simple query to an external service..."*, you usually use DNSSEC. It is not clear why you can't use it here.

Comment: @jww This is a manual Dyn DNS scenario. So it's the reverse scenario.

Answer (score 0):

I presume you mean that the bash script is running somewhere other than the server whose IP you need to determine?

The obvious solution would be to connect using ssh with strict host checking (and a remembered server key) or via SSL with certificate versification (you could use a self-signed certificate). The former is a bit easier to do out of the box.

Comment: The bash script is running on the server behind the NAT and it's supposed to update it's own `A` record.

Comment: You're onto something. I can connect to the IP and just verify the fingerprints against the ones on `localhost`. I'll post the exact syntax for reference.

Comment: ssh already checks the fingerprint re-implementing that logic would be one way to go but I'd just use strict host key checking and copy a file via scp - then check the exit code or the presence of the file

Comment: No `ssh`. Just `ssh-keyscan`.

Comment: Just using ssh-keyscan is insecure. It is vulnerable to MITM. It was never intended as a means of validating host keys - only as a quick fix for populating the known_hosts. You need a full cryptographic handshake to verify the identity of a host. It tells you all this on the man page for ssh-keyscan

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `$IP` is the server's new external IP address, this works by first acquiring the servers SSH keys by running `ssh-keyscan` on localhost and generating a temporary known hosts file. It then substitutes `127.0.0.1` with the given `$IP` and initiates an `ssh` session with the temporary known hosts file to the remote IP address. If the session is established and the key verification is successful the command will exit cleanly. Otherwise it will output the `Host key verification failed.` message. This will work even if authentication with the server fails as host key verification is done before authentication. The script finally checks whether the ssh output includes the given error message and returns `valid` or `invalid` correspondingly.

```bash
TMP_KNOWN_HOSTS=$(mktemp)
ssh-keyscan 127.0.0.1 > $TMP_KNOWN_HOSTS
sed -i "s/127\.0\.0\.1/$IP/" $TMP_KNOWN_HOSTS
RESPONSE=$(ssh -n -o "UserKnownHostsFile $TMP_KNOWN_HOSTS" -o "StrictHostKeyChecking yes" $IP true 2>&1)

if ! [[ $RESPONSE = *"Host key verification failed."* ]]; then
  echo "valid"
else
  echo "invalid"
fi
```